Why I see this error : No reponse is returned from route handler
import { connectDB } from "../../../lib/mongoose";
import { User, userValidation, loginValidation } from "../../models/User";
import { BadRequestError } from "../../../lib/ErrorHandler";
import asyncHandler from "../../../lib/asyncHandler";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getDebugger } from "@/lib/debugger";
const debug = getDebugger("route");

export const POST = asyncHandler(async (req: Request) => {
  await connectDB(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
  const data = await req.json();
  const { email, firstName, lastName, password } = data;

  const { error } = userValidation.validate(data);
  if (error) throw new BadRequestError(error.details[0].message);
  const isEmailExist = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (isEmailExist) {
    throw new BadRequestError("email is already exist");
  }
  const user = new User({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
  });

  await user.save();

  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      message: `Success Signing Up!`,
      success: true,
      user,
    },
    { status: 201 }
  );
});

import { getDebugger } from "./debugger";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const debug = getDebugger("async-error");

const asyncHandler = (cb) => async (req) => {
  try {
    await cb(req);
  } catch (error) {
    const statusCode = error.statusCode || 500;
    const message = error.message || "Something went wrong";
    debug(`Error ${statusCode}: ${message}`);
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        error: message,
      },
      { status: statusCode }
    );
  }
};

export default asyncHandler;


Why when I try to sign up new user, I get this error :
⨯ Error: No response is returned from route handler 'C:\Users\parse\Documents\task-rabbit-new\src\app\api\test\route.ts'. Ensure you return a Response or a NextResponse in all branches of your handler.
Also, even when I get this error I still see new users in my database. so what is going on here? thanks in advance to everyone

If the user is being created, it'd seem that you're missing an await somewhere. The route handler is running but the response is not being propagated as expected.

This is what I’m trying to figure out.. where do I miss this await

The issue seems to be that your asyncHandler isn't returning anything in the unexceptional case:
const asyncHandler = (cb) => async (req) => {
  try {
    return await cb(req); // notice the insertion of the return keyword here
  } catch (error) {
    const statusCode = error.statusCode || 500;
    const message = error.message || "Something went wrong";
    debug(`Error ${statusCode}: ${message}`);
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        error: message,
      },
      { status: statusCode }
    );
  }
};

So, to your point about the user being created, the work is being done but the results are not being propagated back to the client.

Can you please show me in the code how to solve it? I’m new to development and want to learn by coding, and I got stuck here

@GalP See line #3 in my code snippet. Your example was missing a return statement, so the result of the call to cb was not being threaded back to the client (e.g. browser, mobile app, whatever).

Ohhh omg I didn’t see I don’t have return there!! 3 hours of looking at the code! Thanks a lot man

No problem, @GalP! If my answer does in fact solve your problem, would you mind accepting it?
